# Replacing Pandas Dataframe Column with Dictionary Values Based on a Condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

movies = {'name': ['Movie A', 'Movie B', 'Movie C', 'Movie D', 'Movie E'], 'genre' : ['Action', 'Crime', 'Drama', 'Comedy', 'Animation'], 'runtime' : [0, 100, 0, 120,0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(movies)
```

I also have the following dictionary which contains the median runtime of a movie for a given genre

```
genre_dict = {'Action': 107.0, 'Adventure': 108.0, 'Animation': 86.0, 'Comedy': 99.0, 'Crime': 111.0, 'Drama': 111.0, 'Family': 92.0, 'Fantasy': 103.0, 'History': 124.0, 'Horror': 94.5, 'Music': 105.0, 'Mystery': 100.5, 'Romance': 104.0, 'Science Fiction': 106.0, 'TV Movie': 92.0, 'Thriller': 102.0, 'War': 118.0, 'Western': 119.0}
```

I would like to replace the runtime values which equal 0 with the median based on the genre which would result in the following dataframe

```
movies = {'name': ['Movie A', 'Movie B', 'Movie C', 'Movie D', 'Movie E'], 'genre' : ['Action', 'Crime', 'Drama', 'Comedy', 'Animation'], 'runtime' : [107, 100, 111, 120,86]}

df = pd.DataFrame(movies)
```

I tried using a map with the following code

```
df['runtime'] = df['genre'].map(genre_dict)
```

However, this replaced the runtime of every movie as there is no condition to state only replace if the current runtime is 0. Any help on how to include the condition would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and check [`Series.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html). All non-zero values will be untouched, all zeros will be filled based on the mapping:

```
df['runtime'] = df['runtime'].where(df['runtime'].ne(0),
                                    df['genre'].map(genre_dict))

print(df)

      name      genre  runtime
0  Movie A     Action      107
1  Movie B      Crime      100
2  Movie C      Drama      111
3  Movie D     Comedy      120
4  Movie E  Animation       86
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace 0 with None then fillna

```
movies = {'name': ['Movie A', 'Movie B', 'Movie C', 'Movie D', 'Movie E'], 'genre' : ['Action', 'Crime', 'Drama', 'Comedy', 'Animation'], 'runtime' : [0, 100, 0, 120,0]}
genre_dict = {'Action': 107.0, 'Adventure': 108.0, 'Animation': 86.0, 'Comedy': 99.0, 'Crime': 111.0, 'Drama': 111.0, 'Family': 92.0, 'Fantasy': 103.0, 'History': 124.0, 'Horror': 94.5, 'Music': 105.0, 'Mystery': 100.5, 'Romance': 104.0, 'Science Fiction': 106.0, 'TV Movie': 92.0, 'Thriller': 102.0, 'War': 118.0, 'Western': 119.0}

df = pd.DataFrame(movies).replace({0: None})
df["runtime"] = df["runtime"].fillna(df["genre"].map(genre_dict))

print(df)

      name      genre  runtime
0  Movie A     Action    107.0
1  Movie B      Crime    100.0
2  Movie C      Drama    111.0
3  Movie D     Comedy    120.0
4  Movie E  Animation     86.0
```